# PHP ftp_put() upload file very slowly here is my code

Tags: php, jwplayer

I'm trying to upload video on my server and then add url of video in jwplayer account.before upload video on server this code works fine.but now it's takes too much time to submit a form. Actual problem is ftp_put function.This function upload file or video easily in a seconds but form not submit quickly. it's takes 5 to 10min.

```
    //allowable file extension define here.
$jwplayer_source_format_extensions = [
    'aac' => ['aac', 'm4a', 'f4a'],
    'flv' => ['flv'],
    'm3u8' => ['m3u', 'm3u8'],
    'mp3' => ['mp3'],
    'mp4' => ['mp4', 'm4v', 'f4v', 'mov'],
    'rtmp' => ['rtmp', 'rtmpt', 'rtmpe', 'rtmpte'],
    'smil' => ['smil'],
    'vorbis' => ['ogg', 'oga'],
    'webm' => ['webm'],
];

    if(!empty ($_FILES['video_file']['name'])){ 
        //assign $url variable filename.        
        $url = $_FILES['video_file']['name'];
        //get file extension and assign to $extension Variable
        $extension = pathinfo( $url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
        //set default file extension
        $sourceformat = 'mp4';
        //check file extension if not found $jwplayer_source_format_extensions in array script will break
        foreach ($jwplayer_source_format_extensions  as $format => $extensions ) {
            if (in_array( $extension, $extensions, true ) ) {
                $sourceformat = $format;
                break;
            }
        }
        //assign file name to $source_file variable.ftp_put Use this Variable.
        $source_file = $_FILES['video_file']['tmp_name']; 
        //$destination_file = '/cgi-bin/testingvideo/'; 
        // set up basic connection 
        $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 
        // login with username and password 
        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftpuser, $ftppass); 
        //upload the file 
            //ftp_chdir($conn_id, $destination_file);   
        $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $_FILES['video_file']['name'], $source_file, FTP_BINARY); // the ftp function 
        //check upload status 
        if (!$upload) {
            echo 'video not Upload';
            die;
        }
        // close the connection 
        ftp_close($conn_id); 

        $surl = 'http://'.$ftp_server.'/'.$url;

        $params = [
            'sourcetype' => 'url',
            'sourceurl' => $surl,
            'sourceformat' => $sourceformat,
        ];

    if(!empty ($post['title'])){ $params['title'] = $post['title']; }
    if(!empty ($post['tags'])) { $params['tags'] = $post['tags']; }
    else{ $params['tags'] = ''; }

    $botr_api->call('/videos/create',$params);  
        header('Location: video_list.php');
        exit;   
    }
```